# Spring boot - @Component Annotation creates two beans of same type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-bean

When I add the @Component annotation to a class, it creates two beans of the same type (class type) and I get an error that there is no unique bean identifier.

But when I remove the @Component annotation, I only get one bean.

I don't see where the other bean is created.

Here is the class where I add @Component to:

```
package main.serviceconfiguration;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
/* prefix of key in application.properties*/
@ConfigurationProperties("")
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    /* declare key suffixes here */

    /* Then add getters and setters for the keys' values */
}
```

Where I @Autowire the bean:

```
@Controller
@Service
@Configuration
@RequestMapping("/users")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServiceConfiguration.class)
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceConfiguration config;
    ...
}
```

However, in the package explorer of my Eclipse IDE, I see that under Spring Elements -> Beans -> @Component annotation, that there are two beans of type `main.serviceconfiguration.ServiceConfiguration`

one is called `serviceConfiguration`
and the other is called `main.serviconfiguration.ServiceConfiguration`

The error from log:

```
No qualifying bean of type [main.serviceconfiguration.ServiceConfiguration] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: serviceConfiguration,main.serviceconfiguration.ServiceConfiguration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServiceConfiguration.class)` already creates a bean of that type. Generally, you have duplicated annotations on all your classes shown here, which aren't necessary. For instance, why have you `@Controller` and `@Service` on your class? One is enough. And if it is a controller, it shouldn't be a configuration class, so you should remove the annotation `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 4):

That is curious.

What you can do is force a name for the component like `@Component("foo")`
and then along with `@Autowired` add `@Qualifier("foo")`

This does not address the root cause though.

Comment: This worked, but I'd still like to know the root cause of the issue

Comment: I would too... :) Sounds weird that you have two with just the class name and full package name.